# Get time of last sent email to certain contact with Gmail API

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I read a lot of documentation on Gmail API, but couldn't find anything about this, so I'm wondering if someone knows some way to do this?

I need to check the date of the last time I've sent an email to a certain email address.

Comment: Can you search the sent box and then sort by adressee and time sent?

Answer (score 2):

I found out there is this resource:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#request

and using filter like "to:certainusersemail@example.com" for q parameter would bring all sent emails which I can sort by time.